# pthread_kill(0,0) crashes

Tags: shared-library

This is my first question here (as you can probably tell from the poor formatting of GDB's output below :^}, and this may not be the right forum ??...

Using Ubuntu 14.04, calling pthread_kill(0,0) causes a SIGSEGV.  The man page says pthread_kill() can be used to determine if a thread exists.  I must be missing something extremely basic.  I understand that the actual definition/format/structure of pthread_t is opaque (OS dependent) but it seems that this should work, and at worst, return ESRCH.  Please straighten me out.  Details follow:

```
int
main (int arcg, char *argv[])   
{
    pthread_kill((pthread_t)0,0);
    return 0;
}

gcc -g -pthread test_pthread_kill.c -otest_pthread_kill

test_pthread_kill

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1485168 . I downloaded the source and tracked it down.

Answer (score 0):

use `pthread_create(&tid,...)` then you will get a legal `pthread_t` value to pass.  Or use your own tid:

```
pthread_kill(pthread_self(),0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... Yes, passing a valid tid should/does work, but the man page says that by sending a signal of 0 it can check for the existence of a thread ID.  Therefore, it seems that it should be OK to pass a non-existent TID to the function and get an  ESRCH result??  I somehow feel I'm missing something pretty obvious because it doesn't seem likely this function is this broken.

Comment: @EricBuell ok I see what you mean. It seems that pthread_kill assumes it can dereference the tid arg without first testing it is a legal pointer value, hence the core dump. My man page says passing an invalid tid can cause a seg fault. So it's only intended for tids that refer to a running or stopped thread.

Comment: What you say makes total sense, and I think that is the answer.  My man page doesn't mention the SEGV but does say "If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a thread ID"  which lead me down the rabbit hole.  Since it  specifically says sig should be 0 in this case, I *assumed* the error checking referred to the tid.  My bad. :}  Thanks again for the help.  BTW, what OS/version are you using?

Comment: @EricBuell fedora 21, libpthread-2.20.

Comment: -1 because the `man pthread_kill` page says "If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a thread ID.", and the system says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". They should be the same.